# FLUTTER : Convert a Json object to model

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I have been trying to solve this issue from 2 days but couldn't get through it.

```json
[
    {
        "_id": "60bcd42bd8fb4d2dabca24af",
        "title": "test article",
        "article": "{\"insert\":\"This is some test file\\n\\ncode block 1\"},{\"insert\":\"\\n\",\"attributes\":{\"code-block\":true}},{\"insert\":\"quote block 1\"},{\"insert\":\"\\n\",\"attributes\":{\"blockquote\":true}}\"",
        "author": "Ashutosh",
        "createdAt": "2021-06-06T13:56:59.346Z",
        "updatedAt": "2021-06-06T13:56:59.346Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

This is the response i will get from the server and I will use the `article` field for my rich text editor in flutter `flutter_quill` package.

```dart
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:learnlinux/model/articles.dart';

class Network {
  static final String baseUrl = "http://localhost:3000";
  static final String articles = "/articles";

  Future<List<Article>> getArticle() async {
    try {
      final Response response = await Dio().get(baseUrl + articles);
      print(response.statusCode);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        print(response.data);
        return articleFromJson(response.data);
      } else {
        throw Exception("Okay we have an error");
      }
    } on DioError catch (e) {
      print(e.response?.data);
      throw Exception(e.response?.statusCode);
    }
  }
}
```

Model Class

```
import 'dart:convert';

List<Article> articleFromJson(String str) =>
    List<Article>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => Article.fromJson(x)));

String articleToJson(List<Article> data) =>
    json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class Article {
  Article({
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.article,
    required this.author,
    required this.createdAt,
    required this.updatedAt,
  });

  String id;
  String title;
  String article;
  String author;
  DateTime createdAt;
  DateTime updatedAt;

  factory Article.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Article(
        id: json["_id"],
        title: json["title"],
        article: json["article"],
        author: json["author"],
        createdAt: DateTime.parse(json["createdAt"]),
        updatedAt: DateTime.parse(json["updatedAt"]),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "_id": id,
        "title": title,
        "article": article,
        "author": author,
        "createdAt": createdAt.toIso8601String(),
        "updatedAt": updatedAt.toIso8601String(),
      };
}
```

Error

```
Restarted application in 1,226ms.
flutter: 200
flutter: [{_id: 60bcd42bd8fb4d2dabca24af, title: test article, article: {"insert":"This is some test file\n\ncode block 1"},{"insert":"\n","attributes":{"code-block":true}},{"insert":"quote block 1"},{"insert":"\n","attributes":{"blockquote":true}}", author: Ashutosh, createdAt: 2021-06-06T13:56:59.346Z, updatedAt: 2021-06-06T13:56:59.346Z, __v: 0}]
flutter: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'
```

I used [this](https://app.quicktype.io/) to generate the model class

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you are getting a List from article field. Change your article field;

```
List article;
```

Then list article has some map object. Reach the some element from article list as;

```
String something = article[0]["insert"];
```

While handling with json files, we need to check the type of elements carefully.

Comment: No i got it solved. I had to change ```List<Article> articleFromJson(var str) =>
    List<Article>.from(str.map((x) => Article.fromJson(x)));``` to make it work.

Comment: @AshutoshPatole thanks for giving me a clue on what I was handling wrongly. Cheers!